# How to properly sort CFQuery results

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a query that selects all records from table 'ticket_folloup' for users who are marked active in table 'users'. After retrieving those results I am trying to count up each user's total records count and sort by the recordcount DESC. Whenever I try to apply the SORT BY command I receive an error:

string  Can't group on 'requested_count'

I can group by a.DisplayName without receiving any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<cfquery name="get_followups" datasource="#datasource#">
    SELECT
        a.DisplayName
        , count(*) AS requested_count
    FROM 
        users AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
        ticket_followup b ON b.requested_by = a.displayName 
    WHERE 
        a.active = 1
    GROUP BY 
        requested_count
    
</cfquery>
    
<cfoutput query="get_followups">
    <tr>
        <td>#get_followups.displayName#</td>
        <td>#get_followups.requested_count# - 
      #get_followups.recordcount#</td>      
    </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through a ColdFusion query and sorting results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117783/loop-through-a-coldfusion-query-and-sorting-results)

Answer (score 0):

Your sql has three problems.  First, you are grouping by an aggregate, `count(*) as requested_count`.  You should be grouping by `display_name'.

Second, your query does not have an `order by` clause which is what you need to sort the results.

Finally, joining by the `display_name` could cause problems if you have more than one person with the same name.

Comment: So how would I use an order by clause if I can't use the aggregate count?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause needs to include all the non-aggregate columns.  Your `ORDER BY` clause can be any column(s) in the `SELECT` list, it just needs to be after the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, adding order by clause after group by clause solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `a.displayName` is a unique field like a userid, you will need to change your `GROUP BY` from `requested_count` to `a.DisplayName`.  Secondly, you will need to add your `ORDER BY` clause after the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
<cfquery name="get_followups" datasource="#datasource#">
    SELECT
        a.DisplayName
        , count(*) AS requested_count
    FROM 
        users AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
        ticket_followup b ON b.requested_by = a.displayName 
    WHERE 
        a.active = 1
    GROUP BY 
        a.DisplayName
    ORDER BY
        requested_count
</cfquery>
                        
<cfoutput query="get_followups">
    <tr>
        <td>#get_followups.displayName#</td>
        <td>#get_followups.requested_count# - 
            #get_followups.recordcount#</td>      
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```